# WordPress and $_GET Params

Tags: urls

This is an odd problem that I have never run into before with WordPress.

I have a site, permalinks enabled.

The url can be http://mysite.com/page-name/?anyParamName=testing

then when I use `print_r($_GET);` or echo `$_GET["anyParamName"]` I get an empty array or nothing respectively.

A pure PHP file works fine so its not a server issue. Does WordPress do anything with rewiring the get params? Really puzzled by this.

Comment: Where are you putting `print_r( $_GET )` etc? In a theme file?

Comment: I've tried it all over the page.php template file, even before the header.

Comment: any code anywhere in WordPress might be doing $_GET = []; just for fun.

Answer (score 6):

For custom parameters you should register them with WordPress:

```
add_action('init','wpse46108_register_param');
function wpse46108_register_param() { 
    global $wp; 
    $wp->add_query_var('anyParamName'); 
}
```

Then the value of 'anyParamName' can be found with [`get_query_var`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

```
$anyParamNameValue = get_query_var('anyParamName').
```

Comment: that shouldn't have anything to do with $_GET being empty..

Comment: True, but it might extract the value before `$_GET` is emptied by a plug-in/theme (assuming that' is what's happening).

Comment: this answer is misleading and might be construed to say this is how URL params are supposed to work in WordPress, which is not the case

Answer (score 4):

know that this is old question, but we can freely access any post/get parameters inside 'init' hook, (before WordPress changes it) and that is documented [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init), look:

```
add_action( 'init', 'process_post' );

function process_post() {
     if( isset( $_POST['unique_hidden_field'] ) ) {
          // process $_POST data here, read and modify as you wish
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

n order to be able to add and work with your own custom query vars that you append to URLs (`eg: "http://example.com/some_page/?my_var=foo"` - for example using add_query_arg()) you need to add them to the public query variables available to WP_Query. These are built up when WP_Query instantiates, but fortunately are passed through a filter 'query_vars' before they are actually used to populate the $query_vars property of WP_Query.

So, to expose your new, custom query variable to WP_Query hook into the 'query_vars' filter, add your query variable to the $vars array that is passed by the filter, and remember to return the array as the output of your filter function. See below:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ) {
  $vars[] = "my_var";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

For further details please have a look
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

1. the page I accessed had permalink /focus.
2. the main folder had a child folder with the same name (focus).

The right page was loaded (not the folder), but the _GET parameters were empty.
I renamed the folder (in the file system) and the _GET array is now getting as expected.

Comment: interesting, was not aware of this.