# how query string in wordpress receive the value other than post and page

Tags: plugin-development, query-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WordPress and $_GET Params](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46108/wordpress-and-get-params)

I developing plugin in which i receive the value from query string against specific product and show the result please tell any idea or suggestion .

like" http://localhost/business/?product_id=5"

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I don't understand exactly what the problem is so I guess you want just add *product_id* as a query var:

```
function my_add_query_vars( $qv = array() ) {
    $qv[] = 'product_id';
    return $qv;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_add_query_vars' );
```

Comment: Thanks realloc for answer. i am new in wordpress and i view the data from the table on user side