# Detecting $_GET parameters from any page + Cookie

Tags: plugins, redirect, parameter, cookies

I'm trying to create a basic affiliation system plugin that for now, will do the following:

- If it exists, read a $_GET URL parameter in *any* page (for instance http://mysite.com/about/?affid=1234). If not skip the following two steps.
- Save it in a cookie
- Redirect to a clean URL (http://mysite.com/about/)

My issue lies with the first and last parts (reading the parameter and redirecting). I don't think that [add_query_var](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46108/wordpress-and-get-params) is the correct way to go with, since I just want to track the referral and not se the parameter in a query. Any thoughts?

Edit: here's what I have until now:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'test_redirect' );
function test_redirect() {
  global $wp;
  $wp->add_query_var('aff_id');
  //cookie related stuff goes here
  $current_url = add_query_arg( $wp->query_string, '', home_url( $wp->request ) );
  //strip the URL parameter aff_id from $current_url???
  wp_redirect( $current_url ); exit;
}
```

**Edit: Working code, thanks to all of you and specifically @Max who helped a lot.**

```
<?php add_action('init', 'affiliate_redirect');
function affiliate_redirect() {
  $varname = 'aff_id';
  $weeks = '4';
    if( isset($_GET[$varname]) && '' != $_GET[$varname] ) {
    setcookie('wp_affiliate', $_GET[$varname], time()+648000*$weeks, '/');
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ( isset( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] ) && strtolower( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] ) == "on" ) {
      $pageURL .= "s";
    }
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
      $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
      $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    $url = preg_replace('/([?&])'.$varname.'=[^&]+(&|$)/','$1',$pageURL);
    $last = $url[strlen($url)-1];
    if ($last == '?') {
      $url = substr_replace($url ,"",-1);
    }
    wp_redirect($url);
    exit;
  }
} ?>
```

Comment: Use PHP `isset()` to determine if `$_GET['affid']` is set and PHP `header('Location: http://mysite.com/about/')` to redirect.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, where do I hook the function?

Comment: I think `send_headers` is appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work<del>, though untested.</del>

```
<?php
add_action('send_headers', 'affiliate_redirect');
function affiliate_redirect() {
    // it's possible to use 'if( !empty( $_GET['affid']) )'
    if( isset($_GET['affid']) && '' != $_GET['affid'] ) {
        if( empty($_COOKIE['affid']) )
            setcookie('affid', $_GET['affid'], time()+2592000, '/');
        header('Location: http://mysite.com/about/');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just be sure to send the User to the `Url` he really requested, not just the hardcoded About-site. Also, I would use `wp_redirect` to handle the rest.

Comment: This did not work. 1. The cookie with the name "affid" is not created. 2. There's no redirection. In reality, I want it to redirect to the same page, without the affid appearing in the url. Take a look at my code.

Comment: There was a syntax error. Feel free to change the location to your choice. And always remember, copying and pasting unverified code can lead to unexpected results down to permanent data loss.

Comment: After your last revision I get the following issues: 1. links to the site's pages do not work (Server 404). 2. Cookie is not set. 3. calling the home url without parameters works, calling it with the affix gets a server 404.

Comment: Any errors/warnings/notices? It works perfectly for me on any URL.

Comment: Just the 404 with "The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.". Did you make it a new plugin or edited something else?

Comment: I've placed it into `functions.php`. Do you have `WP_DEBUG` enabled? If not, enable it and see for errors/warnings/notices.

Comment: It's giving me a headers already sent error. Note that this happens with the affid parameter only, template links still get 404, while using other parameters in the url renders the page normally. Thanks for all your help by the way, much appreciated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7485/discussion-between-teo-maragakis-and-max-yudin)

Comment: I'd use template_redirect instead

Answer (score 1):

*Answer based on @MaxYudin answer*

```
add_action( 'send_headers', 'wpse85540_affiliate_redirect' );
function wpse85540_affiliate_redirect()
{
    // Maybe even more elegant than simple $_GET, depending on if it was added:
    // $affid = get_query_arg( 'affid' );

    if (
        isset( $_GET['affid'] )
        AND ! empty( $_GET['affid'] ) 
        )
    {
        empty( $_COOKIE['affid'] ) AND setcookie(
             'affid'
            ,$_GET['affid']
            ,time() +4 * WEEK_IN_SECONDS
            ,'/'
        );
        $path = user_trailingslashit( '/about' );
        $scheme = is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        $url = is_multisite()
            ? network_site_url( $path, $scheme )
            : site_url( $path, $scheme );
        wp_redirect( $url ); // 302
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Clicking on page links gives: The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server. Calling the home page with the affid parameter gives a blank page. But this is hardcoded to go to the about page, I need it to go to the same page and just lose the affid param.

Comment: @TeoMaragakis Sorry, but I don't understand your comment. Also: Have you tried adding the `affid` as query arg as I commented in the beginning of the functioN?