# Display value of the GET parameter in a new URL page

Tags: plugins, redirect, cookies, parameter

Here's what I'd like to achieve:

- retrieve the GET value of its parameter from http://mysite/testing/?name=302Beep
- store it in a cookie
- redirect to http://mysite/dashboard
- display '302Beep' in http://mysite/dashboard page

With the help of [this forum](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85540/detecting-get-parameters-from-any-page-cookie), I am able to store and redirect. But I don't know how to display it.
Editted:

```
    <?php 
         add_action('template_redirect', 'affiliate_redirect');
         function affiliate_redirect() {
            if( get_query_var('name') ) {
                $tmpValue = get_query_var('name');
                setcookie('tmpCookie', $tmpValue, time()+648000, '/');
                $url = 'http://mysite/dashboard';
                wp_safe_redirect($url);
                echo $_COOKIE['tmpCookie'];
                exit();
           }
        } 
      ?>
```

Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: Include your code... ...don't make those of us that want to help you have to go to another forum and try to guess which aspects of it you've implemented and how.

Comment: @TonyDjukic added.

Comment: If you use your developer tools, is the cookie still there after the redirect?  I know it's not visible on the page but what about in your console?